# send parameters in url in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have 2 models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     Tag_name = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class QuestionList(APIView):

def get(self, request, tag_id):

    res = Question.objects.filter(Tag_name=tag_id).prefetch_related('Tag_name').order_by('name')[:10]
    print(res)
    serializer = QuestionSerializers(res, many=True)
    data = {}
    return Response(serializer.data)
    # return Response(data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('tag=<int:tag_id>/', views.QuestionList.as_view()) //this needs to be edited
]
```

what  will be the path in url.py file to send id and name parameter and fetch data like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000?tag=4&order_by=name
```

so i get all questions with tag 4 and order by name ?

Comment: The querystring is *not* part of the path.

Comment: ok so how would i achieve this ?

Comment: can someone send me views.py for the query ?

Comment: please show us your views.py

Comment: just added views.py file

Comment: @code_freak4: please consider using a `ListAPIView`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview

Answer (score 3):

The [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is *not* part of the path. These parameters can be obtained in the `request.GET` object, which is a dictionary-like object.

Your path thus should look like:

```
path('/', views.QuestionListView.as_view()),
```

In your `QuestionListView`, you can then filter on these parameters:

```
class QuestionListView(ListAPIView):
    model = Question
    serializers = QuestionSerializers

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'tag' in self.request.GET:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Tag_name=self.request.GET['tag']
            )
        if 'order_by' in self.request.GET:
            queryset = queryset.order_by(self.request.GET['order_by'])
        return queryset

    # …
```

That being said, the above will need extra scaffolding. Here you allow users to "inject" items in the `.order_by(..)`. A hacker could exploit that, for example by ordering elements on related data, and thus binary searching on certain fields.

It might be worth taking a look at [**`django-filter`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter), where you can define based on what elements you can filter, etc. It will furthermore encapsulate the filtering, and thus make it convenient to work with this in different views.

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `tags` instead of <s>`Tag_name`</s>. This because a `ManyToManyField` refers to zero, one or more tags, and furthermore it refers to tag *objects*, not the name of the tags.

> **Note**: Instead of implementing a view from scratch, it might be worth taking a look at
>   the [**`ListAPIView`** class [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview)
>   that can already implement a lot of *boilerplate code*.

Comment: Interesting caveat. I want to hope that Django has an out-of-the-box way to fix this injection vulnerability. It must be a popular enough task

Comment: @DeepSpace: well the problem is that you can not fix that, since a user might want to sort on `.order_by('user__password')` (note that this will use the *hash*, but nevertheless, exposing a password hash is still not a good idea).

Comment: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_queryset' is error i am getting

Comment: @code_freak4: in a simple `ApiView`, there is indeed not a `get_queryset`. Did you use a `ListAPIView`?

Comment: you mean instead of get_queryset i use ListAPIView ?

Comment: @code_freak4: No. Did you make your view a subclass of the `ListAPIView`?

Comment: @code_freak4: you do not need to create that. That is a generic view, provided by the drf: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send multiple Url parameters with Django using this Url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000?tag=4&order_by=name
```

using the path in urls.py try this:

```
path('tag=<int:tag_id>/order_by=<str:name>', views.QuestionList.as_view())
```

you have a good example [here](https://www.webforefront.com/django/accessurlparamstemplates.html), [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/) or find my blog with articles about Django.